# what is meaning of 'default' in ip route command

Tags: iproute2

from `man ip-route`, I see the example `ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0`, but the command SYNOPSIS didn't match these command. How dose 'default' in the command work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` specifies the destination network – it is an alias for `0.0.0.0/0` (IPv4) or `::/0` (IPv6), i.e. the least-specific prefix.

Comment: can use show me some reference about this?

Comment: You are right, thanks so much, I have read the manual of `ip-route` again, and find this statement:"             
                    to TYPE PREFIX (default)
                    ... 
                   There is also a special PREFIX default - which is equivalent to IP 0/0 or to IPv6 ::/0."